# SELECT alias automatically all fields in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to "SELECT *" but table-specific?

For example, I have two joined tables that both contain the field 'test'

```
SELECT
     tableA.test AS tableA_test,
     tableB.test AS tableB_test
     ... repeat for a lot of duplicate column names
FROM
     tableA JOIN tableB
```

I just want to do

```
SELECT
     tableA.* AS prefix_column('tableA_', *),
     tableB.* AS prefix_column('tableB_', *)
FROM
     tableA JOIN tableB
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: No, there isn't a shorthand for aliasing by table. Usually, you should not `SELECT *` in production code anyway - best to be specific about the columns you need.

Comment: *Curious*; does this apply to any query, even if it's not alias-related or JOIN-related? @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @Fred-ii- Does what apply, my advice against `SELECT *`?  I would say so. Frameworks usually do it, but if you are hand-coding SQL I'd avoid it.

Comment: Yes, it was in relation to your comment about `SELECT *` *"best to be specific about the columns you need"* @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just as protection against unexpected schema changes. There are a few people around here who agree with me, but I recognize it may be a radical idea to some.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I never turn a blind eye against people with `much more` experience than I, which is why I value information such as yours and from many others here on SO; *thanks for that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want within a query.

But you can easily create the column names and then paste them into the query:

```
select concat('tableA.', column_name, ' as tableA_', column_name, ', ')
from Information_Schema.columns c
where table_name = 'tableA';
```

The results are the names you want, you can paste them into the query.